# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected "("

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-js

I am new to GraphQL and am trying to query the TfL API for a project with React. I am trying to pass `$arrival` as a variable into the query, dynamically calling arrivals by station ID. It was working yesterday but this morning it is throwing a syntax error, any ideas where it may be coming from?

**Type Defs**

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Station {
    id: String!
    stationName: String
    lineId: String
    lineName: String
    platformName: String
    direction: String
    timestamp: String
    timeToStation: Int
    currentLocation: String
    towards: String
    expectedArrival: String
    modeName: String
  }
  
  type Query($arrival: String!) {
    getArrivals(id: $arrival): [Station]
    station: [Station]
  }
`;
```

**Query**

```
const GET_ALL_ARRIVALS = gql`
  query Arrivals($id: String!) {
    getArrivals(id: $id) {
      id
      stationName
      platformName
      lineName
      towards
      timeToStation
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: It looks fine, are you sure, that the error is caused by this query?

Comment: @flzzz it's the only query I've got, spent a couple hours now but have no idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your schema to

```
const typeDefs = `
  type Station {
    id: String!
    stationName: String
    lineId: String
    lineName: String
    platformName: String
    direction: String
    timestamp: String
    timeToStation: Int
    currentLocation: String
    towards: String
    expectedArrival: String
    modeName: String
  }
  
  type Query {
    getArrivals(id: String!): [Station]
    station: [Station]
  }
`;
```

That doesn't explain the error, but it seems wrong to me in comparison to the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/tutorials/fullstack-quickstart/building-a-schema)

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much! (want to upvote but don't have 15 rep yet)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the top-level query type, you're trying to embed [variable definitions](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Language.Variables) as part of the type definition.  They don't belong here; they are purely part of the query.  `$variable` references never appear anywhere in the schema.

```
type Query {        # does not take any parameters
  getArrivals(id: ID!): [Station]
  #               ^^^ specify the _type_ of the field argument here
}
```

```
query Arrivals($someId: ID!) { # variable definition is part of the query
  getArrivals(id: $someId) {   # bind variable to field argument
    id, ...
  }
}
```